# How to find HTTP header for Text updates on a website?

Tags: html, vb.net, http, post

I am creating an application in vb.net that allows users to sign up for text updates via a simple form.  When users hit the submit button on the form it will send a POST to the website with the actual sign up form and then the website accepts the data.  When I go to get the HTTP POST off of the website it looks very odd and seems to change every time.  I am using Live HTTP Headers to get the data.  Here is a sample of the header content:

```
Content-Length: 952
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_wpnonce"

1d45b60ac9
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_wp_http_referer"

/
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_ninja_forms_display_submit"

1
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_form_id"

1
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ninja_forms_field_1"

(828) 555-3949
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ninja_forms_field_2"

unchecked
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ninja_forms_field_2"

checked
-----------------------------61332911729981
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_ninja_forms_field_3"

Submit
-----------------------------61332911729981--
```

Here is a sample of what I previously have gotten from Live HTTP Headers with a newsletter form for email alerts:

```
fields%5Bemail_address%5D%5Bvalue%5D=blahblah%40email.com&cc_newsletter%5B%5D=1&cc_referral_url=http%253A%252F%252Fpeabodyswineandbeer.com%252F&cc_redirect_url=&constant-contact-signup-submit=Sign+Up&uniqueformid=constant_contact_api_widget-2
```

Any ideas how to get the first one like the second one?  I got them from the exact same section in HTTP Live Headers, but I have no idea how to use the first one to POST data to the website.

Comment: Are you using a different view mode in HTTPLiveHeaders? I have used this in the past also, but found the POSTMAN plugin for Chrome is a lot more user friendly....

Comment: Its' the same view mode as far as I know, but I'll give POSTMAN a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: The first one looks like a form was submitted using enctype multipart/form-data

Comment: So what does that mean in terms of using it in my vb.net code?  So it's not using application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Do you know how I would format for my vb code? Here is the post data I used for another form

        Dim postData As String= "fields%5Bemail_address%5D%5Bvalue%5D=" & txtEmail.Text & "&cc_newsletter%5B%5D=1&cc_referral_url=http%253A%252F%252Fpeabodyswineandbeer.com%252F&cc_redirect_url=&constant-contact-signup-submit=Sign+Up&uniqueformid=constant_contact_api_widget-2"